# GlassFish: WARNING: GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread

Tags: glassfish-3

I'm seeing this error spewing in my log file for Glassfish 3.1.2.2:

> [#|2019-01-18T18:52:34.603+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=36;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0023: Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-8080(1).|#]

I understand that I have a runaway thread but it looks like glassfish is not correctly killing that thread. Because when I do a jstack I still see the stuck thread.  I saw in other StackOverflow posts that people suggest disabling the request timeout, but I don't want to disable this check because I need to be able to recover from runaway thread.

I know GlassFish 3.1.2.2 is old but I need this application to run until we have the resources to port/convert it into another environment.

I'm hoping its as easy as patch a few jar files and restart the server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!